# How to move System Partition to another drive in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning

i just bought two 2TB disks and one 500GB i have installed system on 500GB.
Now in hard drive manager i wanted to setup software raid 1 for 2TB drive, but i have on one of them System Partition, how it happend, can i move it to 500GB drive?

Comment: This question is rather unclear. Is your system on the 500GB drive, or the 2TB one? If it's on the 500GB drive, why can't you just reformat the 2TB drives and create your RAID array?

Answer (score 1):

Windows uses the phrase "system partition" to refer to the partition that your computer boots from.  (The partition that your operating system is installed on is called the boot partition.  Daft, but we seem to be stuck with it.)

The "system partition" is always the active partition on the boot drive.  So it looks as if one of your 2TB disks is configured as the boot drive in the BIOS.  Typically the drive connected to the lowest-numbered SATA port (I assume they are SATA drives?) is the boot drive.  You might be able to change this in the BIOS, or you might need to physically swap the connections around.

Once the 500GB disk is the boot disk, you'll need to make the Windows partition active and install the boot loader on it.  Boot the Windows 7 DVD and try the "Startup Repair" option, this should be able to fix it up automatically.  Once the system is booting successfully from the 500GB disk, you can delete the old system partition.

You don't need to create a separate system partition on the 500GB drive.  Windows does this by default, but the boot loader will work just as well if installed on the same partition as the OS.